# Python Queries - Web Apps, etc

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine

```
def get_songs(requested_username):
   songs = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Song ORDER BY created DESC")
```

The Song db.Model entity has a username property.

How do I find all the songs from only one specific username, if the a song has a username property equal to the requested username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

GQL

```
def get_songs(requested_username):
    songs = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Song WHERE username=:1 ORDER BY created DESC', requested_username)
    return songs
```

Query instance:

```
def get_songs(requested_username):
    songs = Song.all()
    songs.filter('username =', requested_username).order('-created')
    return songs
```

In both cases, `songs` will contain the results of the query, and you can iterate over it and access the objects inside as needed.

```
songs = get_songs(requested_username)
for song in songs:
  # Do stuff here...
```

Comment: @RohitRayudu Haha, not noob at all - you're just learning new stuff. Good luck with everything!

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
SELECT * FROM Song where username="Batman" ORDER BY created DESC
```

you may not want to use Batman in this case

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you check out the documentation -> https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Filters

But to answer your question, something like this:

```
def get_songs(requested_username, limit=10):
   query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Song WHERE username = :1 ORDER BY created DESC", requested_username)
   songs = query.fetch(limit)
   return songs
```